# How can I disable "small caps" in my text in PowerPoint 365 on the web?

Tags: office-online

I have some text in a slide in PowerPoint 365 on the web. Here is the [file](https://archive.org/download/se-web-apps-how-to-disable-small-caps-in-power-point-365-on-the-web-20230810/SE%20WebApps%20-%20How%20to%20disable%20small%20caps%20in%20PowerPoint%20365%20on%20the%20web%2020230810.pptx). I want to convert my text to lower case. How can I do so?

---

To reproduce the issue:

1. Download this [file](https://archive.org/download/se-web-apps-how-to-disable-small-caps-in-power-point-365-on-the-web-20230810/SE%20WebApps%20-%20How%20to%20disable%20small%20caps%20in%20PowerPoint%20365%20on%20the%20web%2020230810.pptx).
2. Upload it to PowerPoint online.
3. Try to lowercase the text in the slide.

---

What I have tried:

I followed [Change the capitalization or case of text](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-the-capitalization-or-case-of-text-1d86cf80-fbef-4380-8d6f-59a6b77db749#OfficeVersion=Web):

> 1. Select the text you want to change.
> 2. Go to Home > More Font Options > Change case.

I tried to select "lower case" and "sentence case", but that didn't work. The text that is selected in the screenshot below is still in upper case:

[image: more font options: change case]

I also tried the following, but that didn't work either:

- changing font
- clear formatting

After further investigations, using my desktop-based version of PowerPoint, I see it is caused by "small caps":

[image: font popup, checkbox under "effects"]

How can I disable "small caps" in my text in PowerPoint 365 on the web? I couldn't find this option yet.

Comment: Image shows 'sentence case' not 'lower-case' being selected. The first character "is" larger than the rest so it's applied.  What tests have you done?  Have you tried `clear formatting`? You have the word 'Experiment' in sentence case so what's the problem?  We can't troubleshoot this for you on this site.  You need to properly identify what is going on "and" how you got there to get a solution.  Is there a style applied to the text box? Are you using a template?  Did you start this in Desktop ver w/ `Small Caps` then open it in the web version?

Comment: Franck, This is not a troubleshooting site.  Please [edit] your question to explain the specific steps another user can perform to recreate your "problem."  Note that PowerPoint does not seem to have a way to apply "Small Caps" however the desktop version does.  Powerpoint will however restore normal characters using `Clear Formatting` which I have tested and confirmed.  If this is not a software bug, then it is something unique to your methodology or environment neither of which we have access to.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147797/discussion-on-question-by-franck-dernoncourt-how-can-i-convert-my-text-to-lower); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You experimented but didn't share the steps another user would need to take to recreate the problem. Troubleshooting problems are problematic on this site and this one is a good example of why.

### Steps to create the problem:

1. Create a presentation in PowerPoint Desktop based on a theme (template) that includes Small Caps, a font formatting option unavailable in PowerPoint Web
2. Edit the presentation in PowerPoint Web

   - Since small caps cannot be applied in PowerPoint Web, it follows that the option to uncheck it is unavailable as well.
   - **Clear Formatting** has no effect because there is no custom formatting applied to be cleared:

     - small caps is part of a default style in that applied desktop theme.
     - If you had instead *un*checked/disabled small caps in PowerPoint Desktop, then in PowerPoint Web **Clear Formatting** would *restore* the small caps.

Comment: Point taken, thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

One cannot disable "small caps" in the text in PowerPoint 365 on the web: it doesn't support that feature yet. One workaround is  using the desktop-based version of PowerPoint to remove the small caps.